# Is it possible to detect if docusaurus is in light or dark mode?

Tags: docusaurus

I have an image with a white background, which looks off on docusaurus dark theme, so I want to detect when the user changes theme so I use a different image.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using the [classic theme](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/2.0.0-alpha.69/theme-classic), you can leverage the [`useThemeContext`](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/2.0.0-alpha.69/theme-classic#usethemecontext) hook to detect the current color mode setting. Since documents support [MDX](https://mdxjs.com/advanced/components), you can create a component that conditionally displays the appropriate image based on the color mode value provided by the theme context. Here is a basic example.

This suggestion is based on using the following docusaurus versions:

```
>= @docusaurus/core@2.0.0-alpha.70 
>= @docusaurus/preset-classic@2.0.0-alpha.70
```

**ImageSwitcher Component File**

Create a react component that can be imported to your documentation

```js
import React from 'react';
import useThemeContext from '@theme/hooks/useThemeContext'; //docs: https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/2.0.0-alpha.69/theme-classic#usethemecontext

const ImageSwitcher = ({lightImageSrc, darkImageSrc}) => {
  const { isDarkTheme } = useThemeContext();

  return (
    <img src={isDarkTheme ? darkImageSrc : lightImageSrc} alt="Example banner" />
  )
}

export default ImageSwitcher;
```

**Documentation Markdown File**

Import the component into your documentation and pass the appropiate image sources to the component.

```
---
id: your-docs
title: Your Docs
---

import ImageSwitcher from '../../../src/ImageSwitcher.js';

<ImageSwitcher 
lightImageSrc="//satyr.io/300/black?text=LightMode"
darkImageSrc="//satyr.io/300/white?text=DarkMode"/>
```

[image: Example Image Switcher Gif]

Comment: I'm not able to replicate James' [issue below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66130767/7168014) or reply to their comment. Both my development app and build work properly without errors.  I'm guessing this may be a configuration difference. In my environment, the ImageSwitch component is a child of the Theme `<Layout>` and it's provider.
https://imgur.com/a/AWsatsl

Comment: This was recently renamed to `useColorMode` in v2.0.0-beta15 as part of a larger refactor to use move `@theme/hooks` methods to `@docusaurus/theme-common`. See https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/pull/6289

https://docusaurus.io/docs/2.0.0-beta.15/api/themes/configuration#use-color-mode

Answer (score 9):

for version `2.0.0-beta.15`, you can get current theme mode like this:

```js
import { useColorMode } from '@docusaurus/theme-common';
// ^^ I don't think it's in the docs yet, but I get the referencet from here
// https://github.com/rohit-gohri/redocusaurus/issues/116

const Component = () => {
  const { isDarkTheme } = useColorMode();
  return <div>{isDarkTheme ? 'Dark' : 'Light'}</div>;
};
```

Comment: link to the docs: https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/themes/configuration#use-color-mode.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of creating a custom component, you can use [Themed Images](https://docusaurus.io/docs/next/markdown-features/assets#themed-images):

```js
import ThemedImage from '@theme/ThemedImage';
import useBaseUrl from '@docusaurus/useBaseUrl';

<ThemedImage
  alt="Docusaurus themed image"
  sources={{
    light: useBaseUrl('/img/docusaurus_light.svg'),
    dark: useBaseUrl('/img/docusaurus_dark.svg'),
  }}
/>;
```

With it, you will not have the following error:

```
`useThemeContext` is used outside of `Layout` Component.
```

Answer (score 3):

Now it is possible with the following, in a `.mdx` file:

```js
import ThemedImage from '@theme/ThemedImage';

<ThemedImage
  alt="Docusaurus themed image"
  sources={{
    light: useBaseUrl('/img/docusaurus_light.svg'),
    dark: useBaseUrl('/img/docusaurus_dark.svg'),
  }}
/>;
```

Reference: [Docusaurus. Themed images](https://docusaurus.io/docs/next/markdown-features/assets#themed-images)

Answer (score 2):

br8dy's answer above works in development-mode, but will throw an error when you try to build the project - Docusaurus will complain that the component doesn't exist within a  component (displaying a reference to [this part of the docs](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/api/themes/configuration#usethemecontext)).

The solution is to use BrowserOnly, as [documented here](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/docusaurus-core#browseronly).
Explicitly, you need to change this:

```
const ImageSwitcher = ({lightImageSrc, darkImageSrc}) => {
  const { isDarkTheme } = useThemeContext();

  return (
    <img src={isDarkTheme ? darkImageSrc : lightImageSrc} alt="Example banner" />
  )
}
```

To something like this:

```
const ImageSwitcher = ({lightImageSrc, darkImageSrc, altText}) => {
  return (
    <BrowserOnly fallback={<img src={darkImageSrc} alt={altText} />}>
      {() => {
        const { isDarkTheme } = useThemeContext();
        const imgSrc = isDarkTheme ? darkImgSrc : lightImgSrc;
        const fullImgSrc = useBaseUrl(imgSrc);

        return (
          <img src={fullImgSrc} alt={altText} />
        )
      }}
    </BrowserOnly>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sets attribute to html tag so you can check this attribute data-theme and listen to changes through MutationObserver.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).